# Comparison of Topologies via Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a set $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume we have proved that $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of closed sets of a topology $\tau$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to compare this topology with the standard one, $\tau_e$ (the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$). If I know that all closed sets of $\tau$ are closed in $\tau_e$, can I conclude that $\tau_e \subseteq \tau$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can conclude that $\tau_e\supset\tau$. In fact\begin{align}A\in\tau&\iff A^\complement\text{ is $\tau$-closed}\\&\implies A^\complement\text{ is $\tau_e$-closed}\\&\iff A\in\tau_e.\end{align}